# Wt adding new widget from http response callback

Tags: c++, wt

I'm trying to add a widget to root() from a http client get callback. When i click on a menu item, i send the get request, and i add a widget based on the response.

My click handler:

```
Wt::Http::Client *client = new Wt::Http::Client(Wt::WApplication::instance());
client->done().connect(boost::bind(&RequestBase::handleHttpResponse, this, _1, _2));
client->get("url...");
```

And the callback method:

```
void RequestBase::handleHttpResponse(boost::system::error_code err, const Wt::Http::Message& response) {
    stringstream ss;
    ss << "test" << i++;
    new Wt::WText(ss.str(), root());
    Log(ss.str());
}
```

When i click on the menuitem for the first time, i see the log message in the console, but nothing happens in the browser. When i click on it another time, the "test0" text appears in the browser, and the "test1" in the console. For the third time, "test1" appears in the browser,  "test2" in the console etc. If i add `new Wt::WText("test", root());` to the click handler, the text show up in the browser immediately after click. How could i make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Enable Wt's server push mechanism. Call WApplication::enableUpdates() when the WApplication is constructed and then WApplication::triggerUpdate() after each modification to the widget tree that was not triggered by a client side event. For example, a mouse click is a client side event, handleHttpResponse callback is not called because of some action on the client.